# DatePicker issue in yii2

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

Hello I have installed date time picker from "https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-date-time-picker-widget"

I have put this into vendor/amigos/yii2-date-time-picker-widget-master

I have added following lines in my composer.json
"amigos/yii2-date-time-picker-widget" : "*" in require section

so it is finally

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "amigos/yii2-date-time-picker-widget" : "*"
  },
```

but when I write following code,

```
<?= DateTimePicker::widget([

    'attribute' => 'created_at',
    'language' => 'es',
    'size' => 'ms',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true,
        'format' => 'dd MM yyyy - HH:ii P',
        'todayBtn' => true
    ] ]);?>
```

It says "Class 'DateTimePicker' not found"

Comment: add `use dosamigos\datetimepicker\DateTimePicker;` at the top..

Comment: I did that but same error.

Answer (score 3):

for me it is working fine, it looks like you are missing some dependency.

1. So I think you should update Yii using composer(if composer is
   installed) for example if you are using windows then go to ur
   project directory in command prompt and run

   ```
   composer update --prefer-dist
   ```

   This should update all the dependencies include in your
   composer.json.
2. Another point is that in my installation the folder is named as
   `2amigos` instead of just `amigos` in every places please try changing the folder
   name if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to right name:

```
2amigos/yii2-date-time-picker-widget
```

And then you have to update your autoloader:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding 
`"2amigos/yii2-date-time-picker-widget" : "~1.0"`
to composer.json file and update composer using
`php composer.phar update`

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-date-time-picker-widget/issues/9#issuecomment-156999145

As bootstrap-datetimepicker is not registered in packagist.org, it is showing this error.

We can do following:
Steps:

1. Install smalot-bootstrap-datetimepicker#2.3.1 using following command
      `bower install smalot-bootstrap-datetimepicker#2.3.1`
   This will copy required files in \vendor\bower\smalot-bootstrap-datetimepicker directory.
2. Clone https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-date-time-picker-widget.git
3. Remove `"bower-asset/smalot-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "2.3.1"` from composer.json.
   It should look like this after removing

   `"require": {
       "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0",
       "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0"
   },`
4. Commit changes using 

   `git add .
   git commit -m "remove dependency."`
5. Update yii2's composer.json to following:

   `"repositories": [
       {
           "type":"vcs",
           "url":"file://D:\\programs\\xampp\\htdocs\\ppd\\packages\\yii2-date-time-picker-widget-master"
       }
   ],
   "require": {
       ...
       "2amigos/yii2-date-time-picker-widget": "dev-master"
   },`

   - Please change `url` according to path where you have cloned repo.
6. run `composer update --prefer-source`.

Now datetimepicker widget is installed.

Answer (score 0):

How did you installed it? Don't try to download it and copy it into vendor.

https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-date-time-picker-widget

Installation

The preferred way to install this extension is through composer.

Either run

```
composer require 2amigos/yii2-date-time-picker-widget:~1.0
```

or add

```
"2amigos/yii2-date-time-picker-widget" : "~1.0"
```

to the require section of your application's composer.json file.
run

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

STEP -1
    Run this command on Terminal at Project main folder 
    ---->curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php

STEP -2
    Successfully installation after run this command
    --->php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker "*"

```
you can see this contant in advanced->composer.jason file
 "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "*"
If you can't see , you can missing some...
```

STEP -3
    Define this library in views-> _form.php
    use kartik\date\DatePicker;

STEP -4
    And last define this given below code in your form at date field

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'xyz_field')->widget(DatePicker::ClassName(),
    [
    'name' => 'check_issue_date', 
   // 'value' => date('d-M-Y', strtotime('+2 days')),
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select issue date ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'format' => 'yyyy/dd/mm',
        'todayHighlight' => true
    ]
]);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use the HTML DatePicker, it doesn't have problems and its easily to use

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'date_of_birth')->textField(['type' => 'date']);?>
```

Comment: I think @Jaydeep Adesara is need a date time picker instead of a date picker.